# What is the quickest way to replace value in cells via VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

Certain cells in my workbook contains value 'A'. I want to replace the value 'A' with 'B'.

They scatter in several sheets. What is the most efficient way to implement the replacement in VBA?

Comment: Why can't you just search and replace?

Comment: I need to automate this action. I am working on an conversion project which includes no less than 50 books. Part of the requirement is that the workbooks must be able to run in two different excel versions, 2002 and 2010, in parallel. The 2002 workbooks are constantly updated.

Comment: Multiple workbooks or multiple sheets (your question says sheets but the comment above says workbooks). If it's just 1 workbook, then you can do this with a Replace All, selecting Within: Workbook in the Options section. If it's multiple workbooks, then you probably are stick with some more complex VBA to open each workbook one by one and use something like Luke's solution on each of them. This is nasty. Is there not a better solution than constantly repeating a replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me

```
For Each wb In Workbooks
    For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
        sh.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Replace What:="a", Replacement:="b", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next sh
Next wb
```

All I did was use the macro recorder to record a find and replace operation, then add the loops.

If you don't want to make the change in all open workbooks, remove the outer `For` `Next` pair, but i figured this would make it easier to run over multiple workbooks at once.

Comment: This will also replace in formula, eg `=A1+1` will become `=B1+1`, probably not what's required.  To avoid this replace `sh.Cells.Replace` with `sh.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Replace`